# Why is the +8 timezone called GMT-8 in the filesystem?

Tags: timezone, terminology

I am in +8 timezone，After my trying， I must "ls -sf /etc/localtime /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/GMT-8"(not GMT+8 file), but after this setting, I can see the result of "date -R" is: "Wed, 03 Sep 2014 18:07:34 +0800", so  I feel that I am correct, but why they use the really confusing name of GMT-8?

Answer (score 6):

The `Etc/GMT...` zones are there for backwards compatibility only.  Their zones are inverse from the usual expectation such that they conform to the POSIX specification, as described in the [Wikipedia entry for the TZ database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database#Area).

The only legitimate uses of these zones (other than backwards compatibility) is for ships at sea.  All populated locations on land have *named* time zones.  For example, you may be in the `"Asia/Shanghai"` time zone.

[You can see a list of the time zones and their current offsets here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

See also, "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).